# Receiving string data via bluetooth - ESP32

Tags: string, bluetooth, esp32, arduino-ide

I have a problem with receiving string data via Bluetooth, and more specifically with its subsequent use.

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

String text = "";

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32"); //Bluetooth device name
;}

void loop() {
  if (SerialBT.available() > 0) {
    text = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(text);
    if(text == "go") {
       Serial.println("Info");
    }
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

When I send something as string data, the `SerialBT.println(text);` function works fine, but the next function `if(text == "go")` no longer works.
The two character strings are not the same.

For normal Serial, everything works fine.

How to fix this?

Comment: I would assume that `text` actually contains more then just "go" which is why they are not equal. Could you try `if(text.indexOf("go") > 0)`? This searches for go and returns the position in `text`. If it is not found -1 will be returned

Comment: It would help to know what’s actually being compared. Write some code to output each and every character in `text` so that you understand why the comparison fails. That should give you your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew Bluetooth was sending some extra variables, but I didn't know how to detect and delete them.
But I have already found a solution.

Firstly, I used `text = SerialBT.read();` to detect extra char. Bluetooth send extra char at the end of string data.
So, I then used `text.remove(text.length()-1,1);`, and everything is already working correctly.

Completed code:

```
void loop() {
  if (SerialBT.available() > 0) {
    text = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
    text.remove(text.length()-1, 1);
    Serial.println(text);
    if(text == "go") {
      Serial.println("Info");
    }
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: I tried to use text.remove(text.length()-1,1); but there was still a space before " go". text.trim() worked for me.